# Adding context to rewrite rules

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

In the following code, I want to rewrite `g . f` as `h` when possible. There may be cases `h` hasn't got the instance of class, but I'd like to do the rewrite when it's possible. I'm getting an error message suggesting this is achievable but I'm not sure exactly what I need to change.

Here is some sample code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

main = return ()

data D a

f :: a -> D a
f = undefined

type family T a

class G a where
  g :: D (T a) -> a

class H a where
  h :: T a -> a

{-# RULES
  "myrule" forall x. g (f x) = h x
#-}
```

An this is the error:

```
• Could not deduce (H a) arising from a use of ‘h’
  from the context: G a
    bound by the RULE "myrule" at trickyrewrite.hs:19:3-34
  Possible fix: add (H a) to the context of the RULE "myrule"
• In the expression: h x
  When checking the transformation rule "myrule"
```

Note the possible fix: **`add (H a) to the context of the RULE "myrule"`**. This seems like it will do the job, but I'm not sure how to actually do this. `a` isn't even mentioned in the rule, so I'm not sure how adding `H a` will help when `a` doesn't refer to anything.

If it makes any difference, the only code I control is the class `H`. I can't change `G`. My code is of course more complex than this, but if I can see a worked example of how to get this simplified example working I should be able to work out my code I think.

**Failed attempt:**

I've tried @Alec's suggestion below but it doesn't seem to work, the rewrite rule isn't being triggered. Here's the code I tried:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

module Main where

main = ((g (f (2 :: Int))) :: Char) `seq` return () 

data D a

{-# INLINE [1] f #-}
f :: a -> D a
f = undefined

type family T a
type instance T Char = Int

{-# INLINE [1] g' #-}
g' :: (G a) => D (T a) -> a
g' = undefined

class G a where
  g :: D (T a) -> a
  g = g'

instance G Char

class H a where
  h :: T a -> a

{-# RULES
  "myrule" forall (x :: H a => T a). g' (f x) = h @a x
#-}
```

Comment: FWIW Im not sure you've disproved my solution yet - usually, if AllowAmbiguousTypes doesn't work, it results in a compile time error downstream. For that behaviour to manifest itself, the rule needs to be triggered in the first place. Triggering the rule sounds like a separate issue. Again, take my comment with a grain of salt - I could very well be completely wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, [one can add type signatures to the variables in the `forall`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#id80). Something like

```
{-# RULES "myrule" forall (x :: H a => T a). g (f x) = h x #-}
```

Now, that doesn't *quite* work in this case because `T` may not be injective. Fortunately, I think [`TypeApplications`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#visible-type-application) gives us a way out of this problem by allowing us to inform GHC that the type variable `a` in the type `T a` of `x` is the same as the one in `h`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

 ...

{-# RULES "myrule" forall (x :: H a => T a). g (f x) = h @a x #-}
```

We don't need to enable `ScopedTypeVariables` (even if we are relying on it to make sure the `a`s are the same) because it is on by default in rewrite rules.

Comment: @Clinton Please do! I am not completely certain that `AllowAmbiguousTypes` isn't just deferring a type error (that won't manifest itself until it tries to inline).

Comment: I'll give this a go, thanks for the answer! (sorry deleted comment before instead of editing)