# Optimisation based on function result type

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

Below is a perhaps silly example, but I think solving this will solve another problem I have, detailed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294423/adding-context-to-rewrite-rules).

I want to write a function with this signature:

```
myread :: (Read a) => String -> a
```

such that, `myread = read`, except when `a ~ Int`, in which case `myread _ = 0`.

Obviously this function is silly itself, but the point is I want to optimise based on return type.

Rewrite rules, or anything is fine here. For my actual problem, if the solution is a rewrite rule, it doesn't matter if there's cases where it doesn't fire, but I'd like the answer to at least give an example where it does.

Comment: It seems like you already have the correct tool at hand - the class constraint on `a`. You don't control the `Read Int` instance, of course, but it seems in your actual use case you do control the definition and instances of the class. Or perhaps I've misunderstood what you mean by 'optimize'? (aside: I think the solution in the other answer doesn't work because `x :: H a => T a` doesn't mean "x of type T a in the context H a" but "x of type 'H a => T a", i.e. the rule would be applied for `(Read a => F a) -> X` not `Read a => F a -> X` )

Comment: I don't control the `Read` class, and I can't make my own `Read` instance for `Int` when one already exists. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly with rewrite rules, in (perhaps) the obvious way, if you recall that the left hand side of a rule is in an *expression* context, *not* in a pattern context. In particular, type applications in the left hand side are perfectly valid.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-} 

module A where 

{-# INLINE [1] myread  #-}
{-# RULES "myread" forall s . myread @Int s = 0 #-}

myread :: Read a => String -> a 
myread = read
```

Even without type applications, the following is also perfectly valid (but may not be in general, e.g. if the output type was `f a` and you wanted to 'optimize' only `f`, you could not have `.. = (result :: [ _ ])`):

```
{-# RULES "myread" forall s . myread s = (0 :: Int) #-}
```

And as an example use

```
module B where 

import A 

fun :: String -> String -> (Int, Bool) 
fun x y = (myread x, myread y)
```

The proof that the rule fires is always to look at core, of course (irrelevant bits omitted):

```
fun4 :: Int
fun4 = I# 0#

fun :: String -> String -> (Int, Bool)
fun =
  \ _ (w1 :: String) ->
    (fun4,
     case readEither6 (run fun3 w1) of _ {
       [] -> fun2;
       : x ds ->
         case ds of _ {
           [] -> x;
           : ipv ipv1 -> fun1
         }
     })
```

Note, this is really a comment and not an answer simply because I'm not sure what exactly the goal is, but the code wouldn't fit a comment.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a new class with undecidable instances?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

class MyRead a where
  myread :: String -> a

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Read a => MyRead a where
  myread = read

instance MyRead Int where
  myread = const 0

main = do
  print $ (myread "True" :: Bool) -- True
  print $ (myread "\"string\"" :: String) -- "string"
  print $ (myread "12" :: Int) -- 0
```

Comment: In this case, `MyRead` has the signature `myread :: MyRead a => String -> a`. As mentioned in the question, in need the signature to be `myread :: Read a => String -> a` (otherwise it won't solve the issue in the related question).